# How can you tell MYSQL to TRIM the X number of characters, beginning from the Back?

Tags: mysql, substring, trim, trailing

How do I write the following in MYSQL?

`SELECT SUBSTRING(value - (1 TRAILING CHARACTER)) FROM table;`

Basically substring(value, 2) trims the first letters. But I need to trim the last letters. I can't use substring(value, -4, 3) because I don't know the length of the value.

Here's another example:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING(value - (4 TRAILING CHARACTER)) in (SELECT SUBSTRING(value - (1 TRAILING CHARACTER)) FROM table);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

E.g., to remove the last 2 characters from string `value`:

```
substring(value, 1, length(value) - 2)
```